# Flycheck reports "Cannot open load file" despite proper "load-path" list

Tags: emacs, flycheck

In my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, I have just three lines:

```
(push (expand-file-name "lisp" user-emacs-directory) load-path)
(require 'init-vars)
(provide 'init)
```

In my `~/.emacs.d/lisp/init-vars.el`, I have below three lines:

```
(require 'dired)
(setq dired-use-ls-dired nil)
(provide 'init-vars)
```

**Flycheck** reports error at `line 2 of ~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

`Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, init-vars`

What am I missing here?

If I change the line to `(require 'init-vars (expand-file-name "lisp/init-vars.el" user-emacs-directory))` then the error is gone. I don't get why `load-path` isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flycheck does not *run* the code, but compiles it instead (to get the compiler's warnings).  When the compiler processes the `(require 'init-vars)` it will try to load `init-vars` from the "current" `load-path` but since the first line was compiled rather than executed, the Emacs session where the file is compiled still has the default `load-path` value, with the extra `~/.emacs.d/lisp` directory added to it.

One way to fix the problem is with `eval-when-compile`:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (push (expand-file-name "lisp" user-emacs-directory) load-path))
```

BTW, I recommend you use `add-to-list` instead of `push` here (or else, use `cl-pushnew`) so that repeated execution of that code doesn't keep adding redundant copies of that directory to your `load-path`.